# Solving a limit without definition

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I would like to find a way to solve this limit without using the definition of limit.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2y^3}{x^9+y^3}$$

I've tried doing some pathways to check if it doesn't exist but I can't find anything. My other option is try to try to use the Squeeze Theorem, but I can't find any bounding functions. Is there a quick tip to see if this kind of limit exists, in general?

Thank you

Comment: Consider the simpler one dimensional problem by going along rays like along the line $y=x$.

Comment: This function is undefined along the curve $y = -x^3$. Chances are it gets pretty big near it.

Comment: @AHusain I think in every ray like y=mx, the limit is 0, right? That's what I get when I check it.

Comment: @zkutch if we take $y=x^3$ I think it actually looks like $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks @ZekeJay. You are right.